# Why can't I use Smarty to create a proper URL?

Tags: php, smarty

```
//Bad way...

 {assign var="article_id" value="`$article.category[0].article_id`"}
 {assign var="article_url" value="https://sample.com/detail/`$article_id`.html"}

　<a href="{$article_url}" target="_blank">Link to article</a>
```

```
$article.category[0].article_id
```

I can get the data "01209394909qs_A".
I want to remove "_A".

URL like this

```
https://sample.com/detail/01209394909qs.html
```

Please tell me a good way to remove "_A"

Answer (score 0):

```
{assign var="article_id" value="`$article.category[0].article_id`"|substr:0:13}
{assign var="article_url" value="https://sample.com/detail/`$article_id`.html"}

<a href="{$article_url}" target="_blank">Link to article</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to use the [`regex_replace`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl) modifier. We can just strip the underscore and everything after it off of the article ID. I prefer to compose string variables in the template using [`capture`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl), but you could use the modifier in your assign to the `article_id` var if you wanted to.

```
{capture assign="article_url"}https://sample.com/detail/{$article_id|regex_replace:"/\_(.*)$/"}.html{/capture}
```